# C# dll using issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am having an issue with compiling a C# dll from a piece of code I wrote. it compiles just fine with no errors, but when I try to include it to a visual studio 2010 C# application the namespace does not show up while trying to call it from the "using"  command.
Here is the code of the .dll file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PAD_SCRIPT;
using System.Threading;

namespace PARKER_SCRIPT
{
    class PScript
    {
    //LOAD_REF




    private void loadCustomScripts()
    {

    }   

    //END_REF

    PADScript p = new PADScript();
    private void loadScripts()
    {

    }

    public PScript()
    {
    }

    public void runFile(string file)
    {
        if (file.ToLower().Contains(".pb"))
        {
            //file = file.Replace(".pb", "");
            p.executeLuaWithThread(file);
    Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR 1: must be .pb file");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    Core cp = new Core();

    public PADScript loadScipt(PADScript l)
    {
        loadScripts();
        loadCustomScripts();
        l.addLuaCommand("runFile", this);
        return l;
    }

    //this will be dynamically be updated when custom cs code gets added
    private string[] getPatchNotes()
    {
        string[] info = null;

        try
        {
            info = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("info\\patch_notes.txt");
            return info;
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.Message);
            return info;
        }

    }

    private string getVersion()
    {
        string info = null;

        try
        {
            info = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("info\\version.txt")[0];
            return info;
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.Message);
            return info;
        }

    }

}
}
```

I don't think the functions in the .dll file is an issue, but by compiling it on the command line I think I am missing a key parameter or something. I know when I compile it in visual studio it works just fine implementing it to a new project. Thank you in advance.

edit: here is the command line I did:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /out:Release\ParkerScript.dll /target:library /platform:x86 /reference:core\LuaInterface.dll /reference:core\System.Speech.dll /reference:core\PAD_SCRIPT.dll /reference:core\lua51.dll  core\Program_lib.cs core\AssemblyInfo.cs core\lib\*.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

The class definition is internal, which will not show up when you reference it.

Define your class like this:

```
namespace PARKER_SCRIPT
{
    public class PScript
    {
        //Code goes here...
    }
}
```